# Account link on mobile is unclickable

Tags: mobile-menu

Does any know how to fix the following highlighted issue on mobile, when a customer login on mobile, the account link and dropdown is unclickable.[image]

Comment: Hi, must be an design issue with it.

Comment: How can i fix this pleas? it's working perfectly on desktop

Comment: Hi, in order to help you I need to see the code associated with it.
would you be able to add the code to your post ?